# Maximum Likelihood Estimate of a general linear model with constraints on the factor loading.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, quadratic-programming

Define $\beta=(\beta_0,...,\beta_n)^T$.

I have come upon a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. Say we have a linear model and I want to find the best fit line. I want to minimize the RSS, $\min_\beta[(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)]$ where $X$ is the design matrix and the $\beta$ parameter is the factor loadings. The solution for this problem for a full rank $X$ is given uniquely by
\begin{align*}
    \hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.
\end{align*}
I can verify this solution by setting the gradient of RSS w.r.t. $\beta$ to zero and solve for $\beta$ but...

How do I find the solution if I apply one or more constraints such as $\beta_j >0$?

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimize a quadratic objective subject to constraints.  If your constraints are linear, this is [*quadratic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).

Comment: I don't seem to understand how to write up the constraints, $Ax\leq b$ such that only some of the parameters are constrained, alle the methods seem to use a some sort of constrains on all the parameters. 
Say I only want to constrain $\beta_1>0$, then the constraints become $-\beta_1<0$?

Comment: Some solvers require "dense" linear constraints for which you must specify an explicit coefficient for each decision variable.  In that case, specify 0 as needed.  Most solvers instead allow "sparse" linear constraints for which you specify only the nonzero coefficients.  In the special case of one-variable constraints, most solvers allow you to specify upper and/or lower bounds on the variables.  But quadratic programming disallows strict inequalities.  You must instead have $\beta_1 \ge 0$ or $\beta_1 \ge \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$.